# Bounded area between the function (and curves)

Tags: calculus, integration

I got stuck in the algebra (I think) in this question. I just want to find out where, and how to continue.

the question:
[image]

What I did:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please take the time to enter at least your own work as text instead of pasting an image. They are not searchable and are inaccessible to people using screen readers. You’ve clearly typed it in *somewhere*. Surely you could paste the text from there and do a bit of cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. When $n$ is large, $\frac{2b}{n}$ is small. In the numerator, you can neglect it when compared to $2b$. In the denominator, you can use $e^x\approx1+x$. This way your sum becomes
$$\frac{b(e^{2b}-1)}{n(1+\frac{2b}{n}-1)}=\frac{e^{2b}-1}{2}$$ Note that higher terms in $1/n$ in the denominator can just be neglected

Comment: great :) thanks. Is there any more official way to do the e^x = x+ 1?

Comment: Yes. $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$